# In highcharts how do I change the color of the line above the categories?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In this [linked jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/gridlinecolor) graph the lines of the graph are green but the lines just above the categories are blue. How do I make that line (and the separator ticks) green? I have looked at the API since my gut says there is a color property on Categories but I found nothing showing that. I have google up and down on this and only found ways to change the color of literally everything else.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
yAxis: {
    gridLineColor: '#197F07'
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

});

Comment: If you're allowed to use CSS, you can do this manually with: `.highcharts-xaxis path.highcharts-axis-line, path.highcharts-tick { stroke: #197F07; }`. I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u2o24mxy/).

Comment: That is perfect. I would have thought there was a way in the javascript but I have no problem using css. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [xAxis.lineColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.lineColor).  To complete the look, I'd also change [xAxis.tickColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickColor)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: '#197F07'
    },
    xAxis: {
        lineColor: '#197F07',
        tickColor: '#197F07'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfnc4qdj/

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Now I am going to find where it says this in the API so I can get better at finding these things for myself.

Comment: I linked the documentation, so finding it should be easy 